# SHA-512 Database Datatype

Tags: oracle, sha

For my exsting java application we are going to use SHA512 hash to store password(Hash & salt) to Oracle 11g DB.Since SHA512 will always have a fixed length of 128 and with a random 16 bit salt i am thinking of updating the column  datatype to VARCHAR2(150). Is this the standard or do you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: Since DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH returns a `raw`, why not store as a `raw` in the database?

Comment: I am not hashing in Oracle but in java code which is why i opted for VARCHAR2(150).